# what is the correct callback in coffee for folding code in Atom

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

I am trying to hack the tool icons coffee file by adding a shortcut to it that will allow me to fold/unfold the code in the atom editor. I have the following:

```
@toolBar.addButton
  icon: 'plus'
  callback: 'run:Cmd+Alt+['
  tooltip: 'Expand Code'
  iconset: 'icomoon'
```

But obviously, it doesn't work. This is a core functionality to atom. If I hit those keys, I can successfully fold and unfold respectively with `Cmd+Alt+[` and `Cmd+Alt+]`.

Using the core callback as in `core: fold` or `core: unfold` doesn't work either

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Key Binding Resolver](https://atom.io/packages/keybinding-resolver) (bundled with Atom) to get the command name after pressing its shortcut.

[image]

There are [several commands](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/3292e3b4df256d8df3395490856e5c55665c1d8a/src/register-default-commands.coffee#L215-L228) to fold/unfold code, including these:

```
  'editor:fold-all'
  'editor:unfold-all'
  'editor:fold-current-row'
  'editor:unfold-current-row'
  'editor:fold-selection'
```

Comment: Thanks! that did it! I appreciate it